# Ruby on Rails model relations, product with options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I have a model Product that can either have just a price, or a price that is connected to a length. I struggling with how to solve this. Which relation should the Product, price and length have? The result I want is that you when you´re looking at a product that has different lengths, you should be able to choose a length from a drop-down list and get the price updated. Been really stuck at this and appreciate all help!

Comment: i think ajax request will be good an instance methods in the model to calculate the new price **or** you can implement how the price is calculated in js and listen to updating the drop menu to update the price in the html  but i think the second option is not good for testing and refactoring issue

Comment: Could you please give an example of how that could work with ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a 1:n or a n:m association between the products and prices.

product for example has a name and color.
prices for example has an amount.

```
@product = Product.first
if @product.prices.count > 1
   # render your dropdown field which contains a list of all @product.prices amounts.
else
  # render @product.prices.first amount
end
```

The rendering and updating in the view could be done through ajax, like @leef already said in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li>
      <%= link to product.name, add_price_of_product_path(product),remote: true %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

### routes

```
resources :products do 
    member do
        get :add_price_of
    end
end
```

### product controller

```
def add_price_of 
    #your code to add the price of the chosen product to the total price   
end
```

add **add_price_of.js.erb** file in the **views/products** directory
and put java scripy code to update the price in the html dom

it would be nice if you notify the users that the price has been add